# write an equation of the line parallel

Tags: geometry

given the point $P(3,8)$, $y=\frac{1}{5}(x+4)$ Find the parallel line.
**What I did:** I know that the slope of the parallel line is $\frac{1}{5}$ but I'm not sure how to find the value B. I know how to find the value of b for things like when P(0, -1) and $y=-2x+3$ I would just plug -1 for y and plug 0 for x making the equation -1=0+b and finding the value of b. How would I find the value of b for this one? Do I have to distribute first? The answer on https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781608408399-geometry-a-common-core-curriculum/160/exercises/14/   says the answer is $\frac{1}{2}x +1$ or y=$\frac{1}{5}x +\frac{37}{5}$ (which one is correct?) Please help me quick as my mid-term is coming for Geometry. Thank you for all the people in advance.

Comment: Do you know equation of a line passing through a point given the slope?

Comment: $8=\frac15 3+b$

Comment: It is simply $(y-y_1) = m(x-x_1)$

Comment: I got $y=\frac{1}{5}{x} +\frac{37}{5}$ is this corect ? can someone confirm

Comment: That is correct; the slope is $\frac15$, and point $(3,8)$ is on the line

Comment: yes that is correct